# How to enable QEMU-Monitor Console in Virtual Machine Manager?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, libvirt

I use Virtual Machine Manager to run several Guest OSs with QEMU-KVM. I read it somewhere that by inputting ctrl+alt+2 should pop up monitor console. It is not working or disabled. Is there any way I can turn it on?

What I am trying to do is to dump physical memory of GuestOS.
With this command,

```
pmemsave 0 0x20000000 /tmp/dumpfile
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Virtual Machine Manager, you most likely also have "virsh" tools installed. You can use it to transmit qemu-monitor commands to your VM:

```
virsh# qemu-monitor-command vm-name --hmp "pmemsave 0 0x20000000 /tmp/dumpfile"
```